# Granting privileges in MariaDB database

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to grant privileges in a MariaDB database, but it's giving me an error message.

```
grant all on ghscom_ghs86 to 'ghscom_frank'@'localhost';
ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected
```

I have verified that the database ghscom_ghs86 exists, so what's going on here?

Comment: `CREATE USER 'ghscom_frank'@'localhost';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to grant all rights to all tables in the `ghscom_ghs86` database, the command you are looking for is:

```
grant all on ghscom_ghs86.* to 'ghscom_frank'@'localhost';
```

The syntax you are using refers to a table, not a database, like you suggested in your question.

Comment: I've just tried that and I get this:
MariaDB [(none)]> grant all on ghscom_ghs86.* to 'ghscom_frank'@'localhost';
ERROR 1133 (28000): Can't find any matching row in the user table

Comment: @FrankSerkland that just means your user doesn't exist.  Have you created  a new user? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

Comment: Leave it to me to overlook something that obvious.  I thought I'd already create the user, but apparently I didn't.  Creating it did the trick.  Thank you for your help.